# Giving angular material $mdDialog a url in angular ui-router state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing, angular-material

I want to show an Angular Material Dialog on a particular url while keeping the previous visited route as a background state.

Hence the workflow will be:

1. User visits a page with url `business/6/contacts`. (state: `business.contacts`)
2. User visits a url `business/6/checkout`. (state: business.checkout)

It should keep the contacts page in the background and load the checkout modal on top of it with the given url.

However for another workflow where user visits url `business/6/settings`, it should keep the settings page as background and load the checkout modal if user visits `business/6/checkout`.

Also clicking outside anywhere should dismiss the modal and load back previous page.

[image: Contacts Page]

[image: Settings Page]

[image: Checkout Modal]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make these modal states as the child states of contacts and settings pages. In this sceneario your url will be business/6/contacts/checkout and business/6/settings/checkout respectively. You have to have some identifier in your url to seperate these two cases. Otherwise when you enter the page directly from url you can not distinguish these two cases if you use the same url.

Here is an example:

```
var checkoutStateObject = {
        url: '/checkout'..,
        controller:"CheckoutModalCtrl" // same controller for below state
      };

yourApp.state("business", {
        url: "/business/:businessId"...}) //parent state
.state('business.contacts', {
        url: '/contacts'..
      })
.state('business.settings', {
        url: '/settings'..
      })
.state('business.contacts.checkout', checkoutStateObject)
.state('business.settings.checkout', checkoutStateObject)
```

Comment: or you can use onEnter instead of controller. ('statename', { url: '..', templateUrl: '...', onEnter: [ '$mdDialog', function($mdDialog){ $mdDialog.alert({  your code here  }) } ]  }

Comment: I thikn using a controller would help reduce the duplication of the code, you can reuse the same controller in different states etc.

Comment: I like this but is there any way we can achieve this on `business.checkout` state otherwise if there are other states like `business.inventory` , `business.canvas` or many other I have to keep track for every single one of them. @cubbuk

Comment: for `onEnter` we have to duplicate too, otherwise it doesn't persist the previous state in background. @neftedollar

Comment: @PiyushChauhan you can set state object into a variable and for each state you can use the same object. I edited the answer using a similar approach. If you insist on using `business.checkout` way, you can check url params in business state and open your modal according to it. But then in this case you have to add this url params to each different state you can show this dialog.